# Get files from sharepoint

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

My goal is to get files from `sharepoint` for every x minute based on their names and if possible also on creation/modified datetime. I have a link to sharepoint where files are stored. I was unsucsefully trying to find some example on internet but haven't found yet. Can I get some advice from you how this might be approached please.